# IntelliJ Idea: custom imports path

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, webpack, jetbrains-ide

I have angular2 (typescript) webpack based project and after update IDEA from 2016.2 to 2016.3 I experience some problems with imports paths in typescript modules.
In order to avoid such long imports:

```
import * from "src/app/some-component";
```

I've added "src/app" to webpack's resolve.root folder, so it can find

```
import * from "some-component"
```

in "src/app" folder.
However, IDEA highlight my import statements and says "TS2307: Cannot find module 'some-component'". I guess that is because IDEA is not aware of such "custom" import roots.

So, is there any way to tell IDEA to search modules in "src/app" folder?
I've tried "Mark Directory As Source Root" and "Language & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries" features, nothing changed.

Comment: "TS2307: Cannot find module 'some-component'" means that the TS compiler can't resolve your roots, not IDEA itself... So you have to set up your tsconfig.json accordingly (use `paths`, for example - see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

Comment: Not sure it is true. Since as I mentioned before, webpack successfully build project using ts compiler.

Comment: it's true:) it's not surprising that webpack is able to work with its own configuration. But the built-in compiler set in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript` is not using webpack configuration files, it just relies on your project tsconfig.json. You can turn the compiler off by disabling both 'Use TypeScript service' and 'Enable Typescript compiler' to get rid of built-in compiler errors. But still you will have problems resolving webpack-specific paths, as Idea provides no support for them

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena). Problem is solved by disabling "TypeScript service" in

```
Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript
```

But I am pretty sure it possible to configure TypeScript (via tsconfig.json) to tell IDEA's TypeScript Service to look into another folders. I guess "rootDirs" can help here. 
[module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)